# Aggregate Rows of MySQL with a Parent

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures

I have a table named 'posts'. It is in a structure like this:

```
post_id, post_content, post_parent
```

The post parent is an int is used to signify if a post is a parent. If it is equal to 0, it is a parent. If it isn't equal to 0, the post_parent is relative to the post_id that is the parent post.

I want a way that I can select the posts in MySQL so that is weighs the posts and orders them according to their parents.

The results should be like this:

- Post Parent
- Post Parent

  - Child Posts with a post_parent relative to the above Parent Post's post_id
  - Child Posts with a post_parent relative to the above Parent Post's post_id
- Post Parent

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what the table looks like so i am making this up as I go along.

```
SELECT * from tableName ORDER BY parentID ASC, ChildID ASC
```

---

This should get you all parents with their children:

```
SELECT parent.ID, children.ID 
FROM tableName parent
LEFT JOIN 
      tableName children ON parent.post_id = children.post_parent
ORDER BY parent.post_id
```

Comment: The structure is:
post_id, post_content, post_parent, i'll try that

Comment: I like your multiple updates.. I was about to question your first one, but now, at last, you got it right :D +1